# Failed rspec test but it should be passed

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I've been analizing the code but i can't find an answer.

i get an error running the next spec:

```
describe 'with valid information' do
  before {
    fill_in 'Name', with: 'Example User'
    fill_in 'Email', with: 'user@example.com'
    fill_in 'Password', with: 'foobar'
    fill_in 'Confirmation', with: 'foobar'
  }

  it 'should create a user' do
    expect {click_button submit}.to change(User, :count).by(1)
  end

  describe "after saving the user" do
    before {click_button submit}
    let(:user) {User.find_by_email('user@example.com')}

    it {should have_selector('title', text:user.name)}
    it {should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: "Welcome")}
  end

end
```

the error is with the "after saving the user" part, and checking the selector **div.alert.alert-success**:

```
Failure/Error: it {should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: "Welcome")}
   expected css "div.alert.alert-success" with text "Welcome" to return something
```

My users_controller sends the flash hash with key success:

```
flash[:succes] = "Welcome"
redirect_to @user
```

and even the success sign-up sends a tag div with class="alert alert-success" in the page:

```
<div class="alert alert-succes">
  Welcome
</div>
```

Is there a way to know what is rendering the **click_button submit** in the test so i can see what is going on? Some way to see the resulting HTML resulting from it in the console

**Note** It's worth it to say that if i change the test to only **should have_selector('div.alert', text: "Welcome"** (without the **alert-success** class), it passes

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find and replace "succes" with "success". Should help